# Proving the Sylvester-Schur Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question, prime-numbers

I recently worked through Paul Erdos [proof](https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1934-01.pdf) on the Sylvester-Schur theorem.

The proof is from 1934 and I was wondering if anyone since then has made progress in simplifying the argument.

It occurred to me that the standard proof for Bertrand's postulate could be repurposed to prove Sylvester-Schur which should be simpler than the Erdos proof.

Is there a standard proof for Sylvester-Schur that is simpler than the classic one by Erdos?